# CircleCI Protractor wait for server to start

Tags: angularjs, protractor, circleci

I am trying to use Protractor on my project through CircleCI for E2E testing.

Starting my server takes a long time (around 2 minutes), and I am getting the following error on my tests (which shows locally when the server has not started):

```
Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://test.blah.dev:3000/auth/login : retries looking for angular exceeded
```

Here is my `circle.yml`:

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 5.11.0
dependencies:
  post:
    - npm run serve-dist: # starts the server
          background: true
    - sleep 150 # wait for the server to start
test:
  pre:
    - npm install -g protractor
    - webdriver-manager update
    - webdriver-manager start:
          background: true
```

I then run `npm test`, which includes the command `protractor conf.js`

I want to figure out a better way to wait for the server to start on CircleCI. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you might find something useful in [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25042323/771848).

Comment: @alecxe I think that the `background: true` ensures that the process is running in the background for CircleCI (it's in place of the `&`)... I still can't understand where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that there are some other steps in the setup of my project that I was missing... in particular, I needed to add names to the `/etc/hosts` file, and some environmental variable to connect to my mongo instance, like so:

```
machine:
  hosts:
    test.blah.dev: 127.0.0.1
  environment:
    MONGOLAB_URL: mongodb://localhost/testdatabase
```

So it wasn't an issue with waiting for the server to start (using `background: true` and `sleep` should take care of the waiting).