# Start webdriver and run test cases in a single command

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

For the past couple of weeks, I have been experimenting with protractor tests. I have integrated cucumber with protractor. Each time, I want to execute a test case, I first open up cmd prompt and do "webdriver-start" and then I open a separate cmd prompt and run "protractor conf.js" to run my test case. I was wondering

1) if there is a way to start the webdriver and run the test using a single command. I came across the concept of "suites" in package.json but can't find comprehensive documentation. There are some simple commands like "npm test" but right now the server gets started but tests don't run

2) Ideally at some point I would want to run a single command with environment variables as arguments so that the test can be run by tester in environment(DIT/SIT/PROD) of his/ her choice.

Could someone please share some insights as to how this can be done?

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "protractor-cucumber-qa-automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample protractor-cucumber usage",
  "scripts": {

    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager update && webdriver-manager start",   
    "test": "npm run webdriver-start && npm run ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor configs/config.js"

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Tester",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "7.1.1",
    "chakram": "1.5.0",
    "cucumber": "^4.2.1",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "3.0.4",
    "fs": "0.0.2",
    "oracledb": "^2.0.15",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "protractor": "5.3.0",
    "protractor-cucumber-framework": "4.2.0",
    "request": "^2.87.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/25042323/6583529 this one seemed to work for me. Also npm-run-all is a package doing basically the same, might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm-run-all . it will run all your test cases in command line.